# Change Iterm2 settings with OSX defaults command

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am trying to do the following

disable Iterm2 settings like "Draw bold text in bold font" from COMMAND line, I know it is easy to disable with few mouse clicks, because I am using Boxen to setup my Mac, just want to be able to get some application settings sorted as well.

I run following command to verify the settings first

```
defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2 | grep -i bold
```

it returns

```
"Bold Color" =             {
        "Use Bold Font" = 1;
        "Use Bright Bold" = 1;
```

That looks good and when I try to modify it, following command did not work, it created another key.

```
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 '{ "Use Bold Font" = 0;}'

defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2 | grep -i bold
        "Bold Color" =             {
        "Use Bold Font" = 1;
        "Use Bright Bold" = 1;
"Use Bold Font" = 0;
```

so looks like "Use Bold Font" is a subkey or one level deep, I am not sure how to modify it.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did some research and found answer myself, post it here just to share with others

"Use Bold Font" is part of a dictionary, and we need to use plistbuddy to change it, here is the command to see the current settings

```
[admin@mb-125:~] : /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :"New Bookmarks":0:"Use Bold Font"' ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
true
```

And this is how you change it from command line

```
[admin@mb-125:~] : /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :"New Bookmarks":0:"Use Bold Font" false' ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

Check again

```
[admin@mb-125:~] : /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :"New Bookmarks":0:"Use Bold Font"' ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
false
```

So basically you should be able to change all the settings from command line.

Comment: Worth noting that iTerm2 now caches the plist contents so although you can change  the file like this, and observe the changes iTerm will ignore them. Using `defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2` and restarting iTerm will fix this. More details here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111534/iterm2-doesnt-read-com-googlecode-iterm2-plist